# Android app on Chromebook throwing dlopen failed: "/lib/x86/libwebviewchromium.so" .dynamic section header was not found

Tags: android, google-chrome, chromium, chromebook

I am getting following error from users who have install my app on `Intel Braswell Chromebook`. I have searched for similar issue but seems like no one faced it. How do I go about debugging and solving this one?

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:270)
        at android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance(CookieManager.java:40)
        at //my app redacted
        at //my app redacted
        at okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar.loadForRequest(JavaNetCookieJar.java:59)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:84)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at //my app redacted
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:250)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:201)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-2)
        at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:265)
        at android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance(CookieManager.java:40)
        at //my app redacted
        at //my app redacted
        at okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar.loadForRequest(JavaNetCookieJar.java:59)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:84)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at //my app redacted
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:250)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:201)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Caused by: at: errorCode=2
        at org.chromium.base.library_loader.LibraryLoader.a(PG:54)
        at org.chromium.base.library_loader.LibraryLoader.a(PG:11)
        at org.chromium.android_webview.AwBrowserProcess.a(PG:15)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.a(PG:79)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.<init>(PG:12)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProviderForP.<init>(PG:1)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProviderForP.create(PG:1)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-2)
        at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:265)
        at android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance(CookieManager.java:40)
        at //my app redacted
        at //my app redacted
        at okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar.loadForRequest(JavaNetCookieJar.java:59)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:84)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at //my app redacted
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:250)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:201)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.google.android.webview-czSKGqLMd8tXGZBl2CdlZQ==/lib/x86/libwebviewchromium.so" .dynamic section header was not found
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1016)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
        at org.chromium.base.library_loader.LibraryLoader.a(PG:46)
        at org.chromium.base.library_loader.LibraryLoader.a(PG:11)
        at org.chromium.android_webview.AwBrowserProcess.a(PG:15)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.a(PG:79)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.<init>(PG:12)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProviderForP.<init>(PG:1)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProviderForP.create(PG:1)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-2)
        at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:265)
        at android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance(CookieManager.java:40)
        at //my app redacted
        at //my app redacted
        at okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar.loadForRequest(JavaNetCookieJar.java:59)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:84)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at //my app redacted
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:250)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:201)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: I have a similar problem: `AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.MyCo.MyApp-0n-eYA7n8ZEekHbO2i0Imw==/lib/x86/libc++_shared.so" .dynamic section header was not found`.

Did you find a solution for your problem?